# Saving multiple Outlook emails to drive using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

Below code saves all items in an outlook folder to my desktop as PDFs. One flaw, The heading of the last email in the string is cut off. So when i send out vottingOptions, the PDF comes up blank for the response. Any ideas? Thank you.

````
   Dim outApp As Object, objOutlook As Object, objFolder As Object, myItems As Object, myItem As Object
   Dim psName As String, pdfName As String

        Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set objOutlook = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set objFolder = objOutlook.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("PDF Conversion")
        Set myItems = objFolder.Items
        FolderPath = "C:\Users\E086365\Desktop\Suz Macros\PDF Emails\"

   Dim objDoc As Object, objInspector As Object
        For Each myItem In myItems
             FileName = Replace(myItem.SenderName, ":", "") & " - " & Replace(myItem.Subject, ":", "") & " - " & Replace(Replace(myItem.ReceivedTime, ":", ""), "/", "-")
             Set objInspector = myItem.GetInspector
             Set objDoc = objInspector.WordEditor
             objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat FolderPath & FileName & ".pdf", 17
             Set objInspector = Nothing
             Set objDoc = Nothing
    Next myItem

End Sub```
````

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to create a new Outlook `Application` instance if the code is run in Outlook. Instead, use the built-in `Application` property:

```
Set objOutlook = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

In the code, I also recommend checking the file path string after all replacing operations run against values:

```
objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat FolderPath & FileName & ".pdf", 17
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Updated to use the built-in application. I explored the "ExportAsFixedFormat" section of the code using microsoft docs. My results were the same when modified. Think it has something to do with the top section of an email (To/From) not being part of the rest of the email.